# How does Saltstack ensure that messages sent to minions by the master cannot be read between the different minions?

Tags: security, devops, salt-stack

for example:

I have three servers master, minion1, minion2, and the master send a specific command to minion1 and minion2. As we all know, Saltstack minion decides what command to execute by reading the messages in activemq. Suppose minion2 is hacked, how to ensure minion2 cannot read the command send by the master to minion1?

Thanks

```
I don't know how to implement this functionality
```

Answer (score 0):

All minions have their own keys. All messages are encrypted. No minion can read any messages for other minions.

Communication is also over TCP sockets, so unless you have an unusual network architecture, messages for one minion will never reach any other minions in the first place.

https://docs.saltproject.io/en/getstarted/system/communication.html